# When i set Webdriver Firefox profile to download all files by default it not working

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

i set up the firefox profile to download all files by default but when it comes to images it pops open a dialog and asked me weather to save or view . The code i use are as follows

```
var folderName = "temp";
            var profile = new FirefoxProfile { EnableNativeEvents = true };
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", folderName);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.downloadDir", folderName);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.download.defaultFolder", folderName);
            profile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/all");

            _webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
application/all
```

is not a valid mime type. The config entry will only accept a **comma delimited** list of MIME types.

There is no way to tell it "all files". So you will need to supply it with a list of MIME types.

This is a limitation of **Firefox** not Selenium.