# How can I force FirefoxDriver to always download a file rather than display dialog

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the .Net binding with the latest version of Selenium WebDriver. I have a test case that I want to automate whereby the user must click on a link to download a file (terms and conditions etc.) before proceeding.

When using FirefoxDriver it always displays the file download dialog. I have tried using the solution posted here [When i set Webdriver Firefox profile to download all files by default it not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890866/when-i-set-webdriver-firefox-profile-to-download-all-files-by-default-it-not-wor) but the dialog is still being displayed.

I have also tried this variation on the profile preferences to no avail:

```
services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting = false
```

Is there a way to force Firefox to just download the file without displaying the dialog?

Comment: the dialog was still being displayed, is because **just as** the answerer in that referenced question stated, `application/all` is not a valid MIME type.. if you are download a CSV file for example, you need the MIME type `application/csv`.  research MIME types, and refer to the question i just put in my previous comment

Comment: obviously i changed the MIME type